# Locating files starting with a string for my hw

Tags: linux, string, find, locate

I have a conundrum and I am not necessarily trying to cheat or anything I am just simply stuck. I am trying to complete an assignment for my intro to Linux class and I was hoping someone would be able to help me find the right solution. I have to:

1. In the same directory (where the last file was found) list all files
   starting with "host" --
2. Use the long listing format Use a command to
   find the file that shows the name of your computer

now the directory in question is /etc and I have tried several commands to no avail for both of these but especially the first one. I have tried find and locate and even attempted a grep and it just is not working as intended. I can't get files that start with "host" at most I keep getting a list of permission denied or files that end in .host and so I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I really need help so I can turn in my assignment. You don't have to tell me what the exact command should be I am just looking for some guidance again I am not trying to cheat just need help to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to Stack Overflow! Here are some pointers.

1. See [globbing in Linux](https://linuxhint.com/bash_globbing_tutorial/) and the `*` symbol.
2. "long listing" is an option for `ls` command, see `ls --help`. The name of your computer (or, more accurately, the *name* of your *host*) is a file in `/etc/`. You should see it when doing #1.

Comment: Thankies! I am sorry for the super late response.